# annotate lines in ggplot using geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, ggrepel

I am trying to annotate lines in `ggplot` using `geom_text_repel`. However, the annotation for some lines is not showing up. How to fix that?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
df.1 <-
  data.frame(
    id = rep(c(1, 2, 3),each = 4),
    time = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(10, 23, 25, 28),
    z = c(2, 4, NA, NA)
  )

df.long <- df.1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(x, y, z), names_to = "class", values_to = "score")

ggplot(df.long, aes(x = time, y = score, col = class, group = class)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df.long, time == max(time)),
    aes(label = class),
    size = 2,
    point.padding = 0.2, 
    nudge_x = .3,
    segment.curvature = -1e-20,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.015, "npc"))
  )
```

[image]
The annotation for `z` is not showing. Also, how can I reduce the annotation to one per line? Right now it has three. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter the data for the maximum `time` with a non-missing value per `class`. Also, as there are multiple values (one per `id`) per `time` and `class` you get multiple labels. Hence, if you only one label get rid of the duplicates using e.g. `dplyr::distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df_labels <- df.long |>
  drop_na() |> 
  filter(time == max(time), .by = class) |> 
  distinct(time, class, score)

ggplot(df.long, aes(x = time, y = score, col = class, group = class)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = df_labels,
    aes(label = class),
    size = 2,
    point.padding = 0.2,
    nudge_x = .3,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.015, "npc"))
  )
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously solution by @stefan works, but @cliu you may also like to check out `library(geomtextpath)` and something like `geom_labelpath(aes(label = class))` for an alternative look. Cheers!